# Enable Cipher in Windows server 2012 r2

Tags: encryption, windows-server-2012-r2, caesar-cipher

I have a task at my work place where we have web application running in windows server 2012 R2.
Now i have to enable cipher and put some more cipher into list which is to be used, but now as i am enabling cipher the default cipher login of my application stopped i don't know what to do please help

Answer (score 0):

```
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256_P256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384_P384
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA_P256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384_P384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256_P256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 *
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 *
```

*Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2 only.